Error while uploading image: column "bytes" is of type bytea but expression is of type bigint
I try to upload an image with Java 17/Spring Boot 3.2.4/PostgreSQL. I tried everything, every tutorial and this is the output:
2024-06-09T23:20:44.470+03:00  WARN 5036 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42804
2024-06-09T23:20:44.470+03:00 ERROR 5036 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column "bytes" is of type bytea but expression is of type bigint
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 56
2024-06-09T23:20:44.479+03:00 ERROR 5036 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement [ERROR: column "bytes" is of type bytea but expression is of type bigint
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 56] [insert into image (bytes,name,time_added,type) values (?,?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into image (bytes,name,time_added,type) values (?,?,?,?)]] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "bytes" is of type bytea but expression is of type bigint
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

This is my Image entity:
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String type;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "bytes", columnDefinition = "bytea")
    private byte[] data;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "image")
    private Baby baby;

    private LocalDateTime timeAdded;
}

Controller:
@PostMapping(path = "/{babyId}")
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> saveBaby(@PathVariable Long babyId ,@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token) throws IOException {
    return imageService.saveImages(babyId, image, token);
}

Service:
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ImageService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImageService.class);

    private ImageRepository imageRepository;
    private BabyService babyService;

    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> saveImages(Long babyId, MultipartFile files, String token) throws IOException {
        Optional<Baby> babyOptional = babyService.findBabyById(babyId);

        if (babyOptional.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(false);
        }

        imageRepository.save(Image.builder()
                .name("image-" + babyOptional.get().getId())
                .type(files.getContentType())
                .data(files.getInputStream().readAllBytes())
                .baby(babyOptional.get())
                .timeAdded(LocalDateTime.now())
                .build());

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(true);
    }
}

I have tried to put LONGBLOB as columnDefinition, tried to compress image and save it, tried to cast from bytea to bigint manually in repository. Nothing seems to work and I keep getting this error with casting.
I also tried @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType"), but when I import Type, it cannot find type=.

That looks like you configured your Hibernate to use large objects for your images. A very bad idea - use bytea instead.

I ran into the same error while upgrading my application from an old Spring Boot version to 3.3, on which the JPA version does not support @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType"), Even though I tried many solutions almost all of them didn't work for me, I worked around the error using native SQL:
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("Your sql insert string"); 
query.executeUpdate();

The field on your entity remains unchanged:
@Lob
@Column(name = "bytes", columnDefinition = "bytea")
private byte[] data;

